# Eager-loaded related objects which are null are being lazy-loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, poco, eager-loading

I'm eager-loading (by using .Include()) related entities in order to minimize the number of SQL queries generated for a particularly "massive" datagrid. In the POCOs, the related entities are public virtual navigation properties, meaning that they are otherwise lazy-loaded. I want to keep the default behavior of lazy-loading these related entities, as it suits me best for other parts of the project.

Now, what happens is that after eager-loading the related entities, I can see that there are still a fair amount of queries generated. And this is queries solely for related entities *being null* (null simply because the sql joins "found" no related data).

This led me to believe that the EF tries to lazy-load those entities (thinking they are not yet loaded) as soon as I access them later on in the presentation layer.

Have I missed something fundamental, or is there any way to work around this problem?

**Sample code**
Using a repository pattern, here are some simplified methods (omitting paging, sorting, filtering etc).

*Get-method in generic repository*

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get(
    Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = set;

    ...

    // Include properies for eager loading
    if (includes != null)
    {
       query = includes.Aggregate(query, 
          (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    }

    ...

    return query.ToList();
}
```

*Above is called from a service class, something like this*

```
...
context.Licenses.Get(
    includes: new Expression<Func<License, object>>[] { l => l.Comment }
);
...
```

*License POCO*

```
public class License
{
    public License()
    {
    }

    // Primitive properties
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    // Navigation properties
    public virtual LicenseComment Comment { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

*LicenseComment POCO*

```
public class LicenseComment
{
    public LicenseComment()
    {
    }

    // Primitive properties
    public string LicenseID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

*Accessing the property in a MVC Razor view (or in a Model for that sake)*

```
<span>@license.Comment</span>
```

Extra SQL queries are generated whenever I try access a License.Comment that is null (looked it up via SQL Server Profiler), which seems to me that Entity Framework lazy-loading kicks in, even though I eagerly included this property.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Ladislav that it should not happen and tested that the "normal" behaviour is the following:

If you load the license including comment...

```
var license = context.Licenses.Include(l => l.Comment).Single(l => l.ID == 1);
```

...EF marks the navigation property as loaded:

```
var isCommentLoaded = context.Entry(license).Reference(l => l.Comment).IsLoaded;
```

No matter if the comment is `null` or not `isCommentLoaded` will be `true` and no lazy loading query is issued when you access the `Comment` property.

Even if you don't use eager loading...

```
var license = context.Licenses.Single(l => l.ID == 1);
```

...`isCommentLoaded` will be `true` *if* the foreign key from license to comment in the database is `NULL` (but it will be `false` if the foreign key is not `NULL`). The reason is that EF always loads the foreign key in the `SELECT` statement into the context and if this key is `NULL` EF knows that there is no related comment in the database and marks the navigation property as already loaded to avoid unnecessary lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. What you describe is exactly what I thought should happen - i.e. that EF maintains a loaded state for navigation properties. Looks like I need to test this more thoroughly, especially with Reference().IsLoaded and the actual association setup, even though looks fine.

The last resort is the suggestion from @Ladislav, but that shouldn't be necessary!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to try it know but I expect this should not happen. Anyway, if you have a page where you don't want lazy loading to happen you can simply turn in off for that page:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

or you can turn off proxy creation for those queries - unproxied entities cannot use lazy loading:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly your situation, I had something similar and I pinpointed that there was an additional property access that was not part of the original include.